# Pretend like vs pretend that

Tags: verbs

I want to know if there's any difference in meaning between the two sentences below:

"I pretended like it was a small confusion."
"I pretended that it was a small confusion."

I'm not a native speaker, but both somehow sound correct. However, I can't really pin down the difference, although I feel there is one.

Comment: The use of *like* would be correct in this sentence: *I pretended just like you did.* It could even be expanded to cover both uses: *[I pretended]* ***that*** *[it was a small matter] [just* ***like*** *you did]*.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is incorrect because *pretend* and *like* here both mean that something seems to be a small confusion. So instead of using words that have the same meaning twice, you can just use *pretend (that)* like you did in the second sentence. However, in modern usage *like* can be thrown in to signify some uncertainity and it is often just used as a catchphrase. Note that using *that* is optional, you could just as well leave it out.